# Python: Unable to import two interdependent classes that contain only static methods

Tags: python, static-methods, circular-dependency

I am trying to import two interdependent classes called `A` and `B` located into a folder named 'static_classes', in order to call their static methods within my program.

### `A` class code:

```
from b import B

class A:
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print('a')
        B.b()
```

### `B` class code:

```
import sys

if 'A' not in sys.modules:
    from a import A

class B:
    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print('b')
        A.a()
```

### Main code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./static_classes')

from a import A
from b import B

A.a()
B.b()
```

However after running the program, I get a runtime error message saying:

> ImportError: cannot import name B

I don't know why it's not possible to import the class `B`. What I'm missing?

Comment: You cannot cyclic import!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the link to the dupe @NannanAV.

Comment: @NannanAV Can I pass the class `A` as parameter for the `b` method?

Comment: @Kais No, you cannot.! I strongly urge you to go through the above link in case you already haven't. What you might be able to do in this case is pass a variable x to the b method and call x.a() inside b. Assign x = A or A() before you want to call B.b(x). 
But I'm still not sure as to why you want to create an infinite loop!